# FFT implementation using Danielson-Lanczos Lemma

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to understand FFT algorithm explained [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-simple-and-efficient-fft-implementatio/199500857)

```
FFT(x) {   n=length(x);   
if (n==1) return x;   
m = n/2;   
X = (x_{2j})_{j=0}^{m-1};   
Y = (x_{2j+1})_{j=0}^{m-1};  
X = FFT(X);   
Y = FFT(Y);  
U = (X_{k mod m})_{k=0}^{n-1};   
V = (g^{-k}Y_{k mod m})_{k=0}^{n-1};   
return U+V; 
}
```

The author says that the above comes from [Danielson-Lanczos Lemma](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~pdh1001/Talks/parallel_fft/node5.html).

I am unable to understand what is the meaning of the lines:

X = (x_{2j})_{j=0}^{m-1};

Y = (x_{2j+1})_{j=0}^{m-1};

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the first line is "Let $X$ be an array of length $m$ (with indices running from $0$ to $m-1$) such that $X_j = x_{2j}$ for $j \in \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$." The second line has a similar meaning, with $Y_j = x_{2j+1}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks. Which langauge is this BTW?

Comment: It's pseudocode, so no particular language.

Comment: @gpuguy: perhaps you meant "which language expresses subscript with `_` and superscript with `^` and grouping with `{` `}`?  The answer is TeX/LaTeX, and various informal kinds of ascii math.  Put your statements inside `$` signs on Stackexchange and it will magically turn into well formatted math!  For example `$X = (x_{2j})_{j=0}^{m-1}$` yields $X = (x_{2j})_{j=0}^{m-1}$.